# AngularJS Interceptor to Redirect

Tags: angularjs

ExpressJS is sending the following response...

```
res.send('ItemUploaded');
```

I'm trying to get AngularJS to see this response via an Interceptor and perform a redirect.  Does anyone have sample code where Angular catches a server response (such as my "ItemUploaded") and performs a redirect to a partial (via $location)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the factory for the interceptor:

```
 .factory('InterceptorService',['$q', '$location', function( $q, $location, $http){
     var InterceptorServiceFactory = {};

     var _request = function(config){
         //success logic here
         return config;
     }

     var _responseError = function(rejection) {
            //error here. for example server respond with 401
         return $q.reject(rejection);
     }

     InterceptorServiceFactory.request = _request;
     InterceptorServiceFactory.responseError = _responseError;
     return InterceptorServiceFactory;

    }]);
```

then register the interceptor:

```
.config(["$httpProvider", function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('InterceptorService'); 
}]);
```

Every request coming will be passed here.

Comment: I'm having some troubles getting the logic to function within this.  Within the "success logic" area of _request, how would I go about listening for node's res.send('ItemUploaded')? And would this be changed to _response?

Comment: THIS factory is defined to be an Interceptor what Interceptor do is to process the respond coming from the server before it goes to your services or controllers for example if the server respond with 401 which means unauthorized you can redirect the user to a log in page and _request just returns the config object to your config function.

Answer (score 4):

> This works fine. I have used it in my application.

```
var interceptor = function ($q, $location) {
            return {
                request: function (config) {//req
                    console.log(config);
                    return config;
                },

                response: function (result) {//res
                    console.log('Repos:');
                    console.log(result.status);
                    return result;
                },

                responseError: function (rejection) {//error
                    console.log('Failed with', rejection.status, 'status');
                    if (rejection.status == 403) {
                        $location.url('/dashboard');
                    }

                    return $q.reject(rejection);
                }
            }
        };
        module.config(function ($httpProvider) {
            $httpProvider.interceptors.push(interceptor);
        });
```

Comment: Where are you placing the 'interceptor' variable? Inside the service possibly?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a interceptor factory which will redirect if it gets a matching result.

```
angular
.module('app')
.factory("httpinterceptor", ["$location", 

    function(location) {
        return {
            'response': function(response) {

                if (response.data === "ItemUploaded") {
                    location.path("/ItemUploaded")
                }

            }

        }
    }
]);
```