# Angular JS Interceptor checking for response data returns html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, intercept

I am trying to implement a interceptor on Angular JS side , for which I will check for a particular response and navigate user to some other page . This is my  interceptor

```
App.factory('InterceptorService',['$q', '$location', function( $q, $location, $http){
var InterceptorServiceFactory = {};

var _request = function(config){
   console.log('Coming inside');
   console.log(config);
    return config;
}

var _response = function(response){
    console.log('Coming inside for Result');
    console.log(response);
    if (response.data.code == "USER_TIMEDOUT") {
        window.location.href = '/unrestricted/jsp/FormLogin.jsp';
        alert(worked);
    }
     return response;
 }

InterceptorServiceFactory.request = _request;
InterceptorServiceFactory.response = _response;
return InterceptorServiceFactory;
}]);

App.config(["$httpProvider", function ($httpProvider) {
$httpProvider.interceptors.push('InterceptorService'); 
}]);
```

This is my API response from Spring Interceptor

```
    {
"code": "USER_TIMEDOUT",
"message": "User session timedout for requestUri=/services/search/Employee"
}
```

I am trying to check my response and check for the code and if the code matches I'm trying to take oput him to another screen . But whenever I see the response on console inside data it is having the Html .

Whene I analyse the Network tab , I am able to see API call has failed with response 401 . And all other HTML has loaded , while loading of the html . Response data is coming inside the Html . so what I am missing in my Interceptor ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since response code is 401 (over 400 is considered a request failure),
you need to use

```
InterceptorServiceFactory.responseError = _response;
```

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25268747/angularjs-interceptor-to-redirect) for more details